How to compile an Astro App with the development .env file
I have an app in Astro and I need to be able to compile but use the variables from the .env.development file since it goes to a dev server and not production. I have tried to modify the package.json file like this
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro check && astro build --mode development",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },

It also doesn't work if I use
"build": "astro check && astro build --env=development"

But it doesn't work, always using npm run build it takes the variables from the env.production file, how can I choose the file I want it to use

did you try "build": "NODE_ENV=development astro build" ? btw. Astro uses vite under the hood for this
